# Angles in pyramid

Tags: geometry

[image]

We have to find the value of $\cos\theta$.

I tried it alot. But could not able to do it.

[Solution given in the book](http://dc.allenbpms.in/testpaper/solution/d8839-17-636224186622314570-017s.gif)

Comment: It would have been better if you typed the question and only pasted the figure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the slant side (= OA = …) be 1 unit.

[image]

Find x from the first figure. (x will then be $\sqrt {2 - \sqrt 2}$.)

Next, from the subsequent figures,  find y and z.

Finally apply cosine law to the shaded triangle.

**Added:** $\theta$, the angle between two planes (OBA and OBC) can only be found by observing the following set of rules:-

(1) Find the line of intersection of the 2 planes (ie. OB);

(2) In plane OBC, find a line perpendicular to OB (Note that many lines qualify but I choose CP.  Then, $\angle OPC = 90^0$);

(3) Repeat step 2 for plane OBA (I use AP);

(4) Test if the lines found in (1), (2) and (3) must be concurrent at the same point. If not, we have to re-do (2) and (3). The choices that I made passed the test and that point is P.

(5) $\theta = \angle CPA$.

Comment: What is point P

Comment: @user123733 See added.

Answer (score 2):

This works out nicely with vectors.

Place $A, B, C, D$ on the $x$ and $y$ axes. Let $A = (1, 0, 0), B = (0, -1, 0), C = (-1, 0, 0), D = (0, 1, 0)$

$O$ must be on the $z$ axis by symmetry and $O = (0, 0, h)$ The only question is the value of $h$. Since angle $AOB = 45$ degrees, $OA \cdot OB = ||OA|| ||OB|| cos 45$ degrees.

$$(1, 0, -h) \cdot (0, -1, -h) = \sqrt{1^2 + 0 + h^2} \sqrt{0 + 1^2 + h^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

$$h^2 = (1 + h^2) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

$$\sqrt{2} h^2 = 1 + h^2$$

$$(\sqrt{2} - 1) h^2 = 1$$

$$ h = \sqrt{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-1} }$$
Or equivalently, rationalizing.
$$h = \sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}$$

We would like the normals to the triangles $OAB $ and $OBC$

$OA = (1, 0, -h), OB = (0, -1, -h), $ and $OC = (-1, 0, -h)$

$OA \cdot OB  = det$

$$\pmatrix{i &j &k\\1 &0&-h\\0&-1&-h} $$

$$= (-h, h, -1)$$ = normal to face $OAB = N_1$

$$OB \cdot OC = det$$

$$\pmatrix{i &j &k\\0 & -1 &-h\\-1& 0 &-h} $$

$$ = (h, h, -1) $$ = normal to face $OBC = N_2$

Then $N_1 \cdot N_2 = (-h, h, -1) \cdot (h, h, -1) = ||N_1||||N_2|| cos \theta$

$$ -h^2 + h^2 + 1 = \sqrt{h^2 + h^2 + 1} \sqrt{h^2 + h^2 + 1}cos \theta$$

$$ cos \theta = \frac{1}{2h^2 + 1}$$

$$cos \theta = \frac{1}{2(\sqrt{2} + 1) + 1} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2} + 3}$$

$$ \theta \approx 80.12 degrees$$

As always I do not promise perfect accuracy -- there may be a typo or sign error in there so proofread before you trust it.
But the method is sound and the amount of calculation is reasonable.

Addenda:

Possibly -- please see comment below -- $\theta$ = 180 degrees - 80.12 degrees = 99.88 degrees, 
I plan to build a model and check.

This method is very similar to the text method given ( did not look first :-)  ) but my calculations came out a little differently. As always, double-check first drafts.

Comment: How do you know angle between N1 and N2 is $\theta$

Comment: Some 3D geometry to learn. Take two planes -  book or clipboard and table will do as models. Prop book or clipboard up so it meets the table at some angle other than 90. Take two pencils to be the normals. Hold each pencil orthogonal  to one plane. You see where the pencils cross they form two angles. On of these is the same as the dihedral angle $\theta$ between the planes, and the other is $ \pi - \theta$ or 180 degrees $- \theta$. Depending on whether you do $N_1 x N_2$ or $N_2 x N_1$ you'll get one or the other, so use intuition or directionality to choose the correct one of the two.

Comment: Now that I take a second look, the angle interior to the pyramid looks more like 180 degrees - 80.12 degrees $\approx$ 99.88 degrees. I am planning to build a model to look at this. (Pragmatic math.)

That's why I always say to check my first drafts. Good but not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

HINTS:

Shall be brief, hope you fill in details.

Let $AB= 4 b$ then side of inner square on base $ 2 \sqrt 2 b = 2d $ say

Let $OA = h. \, $ Projections on midface and base are $ h \cos \beta, h \sin \beta \,$ where $ 2\beta = AOB$

If $H$ is side of *dihedral angle* $ 2 \gamma$ between slant faces

$$ \dfrac{1}{H^2}=\dfrac{1}{(h \cos \beta)^2}+ \dfrac{1}{(h \sin \beta)^2} $$

$$ \sin \gamma= \frac{d}{H} $$